# Generating a 3D numpy array from variably-shaped 2D numpy arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, tensorflow, librosa

I am generating a large number of mel spectrograms to train a NN for phoneme detection.

Each mel spectrogram (generated with librosa.core.melspectrogram in Python) is represented as a 2D numpy array, where axis 1 (the length of the vectors) varies from spectrogram to spectrogram. They vary from shape (128, 2) to (128, 200).

In order to generate a 3D array, all spectrograms must have the same shape, so I'm guessing that I should append zeros to the ends of vectors that are shorter than 200. Then I can just add them all to a Python list, call np.array on it and a 3D numpy array will be generated, right?

I have attempted this myself unsuccessfully. All help is appreciated.

Edit: (code has been requested, this is essentially what I want to do)

```
spectrograms = []

for audio_array in all_audio_arrays:
    audio_array, sr = librosa.core.load(audio_file, sr=sample_rate, mono=True)
    melspectrogram = librosa.feature.melspectrogram(y=audio_array, sr=sample_rate, S=None, n_fft=window_size, hop_length=hop_length)
    # melspectrogram is a 2D numpy array
    # the shape could be between (128, 2) and (128, 200)
    spectrograms.append(melspectrogram)

# I want this to be 3D
np.asarray(spectrograms)
```

Comment: Please paste your code here if you have already tried to solve the problem – that way we can have something to work with.

Comment: I am under NDA to not release my code, it's less headache for me to simply not paste any of it. I think that I described the nature of the problem well enough.

Comment: Release an MCVE - https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve?

Comment: You could concatenate a `np.zeros((128,198))` array on to the (128,2) one to make a (128,200) array.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer if it's an appropriate approach for your learner to pad with zeros. But doing so is quite easy using [`np.concatenate`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html)

```
import numpy as np

a = np.ones((128,2))
b = np.ones((128,200))

padding = np.zeros((a.shape[0], b.shape[1] - a.shape[1])) #(128, 198)
a = np.concatenate((a, padding), axis=1)

print (a.shape)

>>> (128L, 200L)
```

Comment: Thanks! I also found that this will work: space = 200 - arr.shape[1];
                arr = np.pad(arr, (0, space), 'constant', constant_values=(0,0))

Comment: Are you sure that does the right thing? I end up with shape `(326,200)` since [`pad`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.pad.html) seems to pad in both directions. I am using numpy 1.14.2

Comment: `np.pad` may be overkill for a simple task like  this.  It allows you to added values on all 4 sides (of a 2d array), and with many modes.